# Color gradient in C

Tags: c

I'm taking my first steps in C, and was trying to make a gradient color function, that draws a bunch of rectangles to the screen (vertically).
This is the code so far:

```
void draw_gradient(uint32_t start_color, uint32_t end_color) {
    int steps = 8;
    int draw_height = window_height / 8;
    
    //Change this value inside the loop to write different color
    uint32_t loop_color = start_color;

    for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
        draw_rect(0, i * draw_height, window_width, draw_height, loop_color);
    }
}
```

Ignoring the `end_color` for now, I want to try and pass a simple red color in like `0xFFFF0000` (ARGB)..and then take the red 'FF' and convert it to an integer or decrease it using the `loop_color` variable.

I'm not sure how to go get the red value from the hexcode and then minipulate it as a number and then write it back to hex..any ideas?

So in 8 steps the code should for example go in hex from `FF` to `00` or as integer from `255` to `0`.

Comment: Normally you will treat each part of the color (A, R, G, B) separately. Number of steps in your case is rectangle height (or width) and step is `(end-start)/height`. That's it - every loop you re-calculate each color with `start + curr_y * step`, of course for each `4` parts of full color.

Comment: Hmm it's the calculation that I'm stuck at..can I just combine 4 integers (0-255) into a uint32 somehow? The value that's being passed to the draw function is a hex code.

Comment: Aside: the loop control should ensure that the height is fully covered in the cases where it is < 8 or not a multiple of 8. For example, suppose the height is 15. You'll get 8 bands of width 1 and a gap of 7.

Comment: Well let's focus on the question first ;) all the stuff with rectangles and multiples I'll figure out. I just need to know how to manipulate the color values.

Comment: `uint32_t r = (start_color >> 24) & 0xFF;` etc then  `uint32_t colorcode = (r << 24) | (g << 16) | b;`

Comment: You are confusing _representation_ with _presentation_; bit FF and 255  are _integers_,they are simply different presentations of the same integer value stored in _binary_.  Moreover you are not "writing it back in hex", you are simply modifying bits 16 to 24 of the ARGB integer.  Hexadecimal is used because each digit represents exactly 4 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have said, your color is in RGB format. This calculation assumes vertical gradient - meaning from top to the bottom (linear lines).

Steps to do are:

- Get number of lines to draw; this is your rectangle height
- Get A, R, G, B color components from your start and end colors

```c
uint8_t start_a = start_color >> 24;
uint8_t start_r = start_color >> 16;
uint8_t start_g = start_color >> 8;
uint8_t start_b = start_color >> 0;
uint8_t end_a = end_color >> 24;
uint8_t end_r = end_color >> 16;
uint8_t end_g = end_color >> 8;
uint8_t end_b = end_color >> 0;
```

- Calculate step for each of the components

```c
float step_a = (float)(end_a - start_a) / (float)height;
float step_r = (float)(end_r - start_r) / (float)height;
float step_g = (float)(end_g - start_g) / (float)height;
float step_b = (float)(end_b - start_b) / (float)height;
```

- Run for loop and apply different step for each color

```c
for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
    uint32_t color = 0 |
        ((start_a + i * step_a) & 0xFF) << 24 |
        ((start_r + i * step_r) & 0xFF) << 16 |
        ((start_g + i * step_g) & 0xFF) << 8 |
        ((start_b + i * step_b) & 0xFF) << 0
    draw_horizontal_line(i, color);
}
```

It is better to use float for `step_x` and multiply/add on each iteration. Otherwise with integer rounding, you may never increase number as it will always get rounded down.